# WordPress Ajax Call inserting data but success response false

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to post data to a custom table via Ajax call and it works fine (rows are being inserted in MySQL custom table) but I'm not getting success response true in `console.log`.

Here is my code.

PHP

```
function create_link() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( check_ajax_referer( 'create_link', 'nonce', false ) == false ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "custom_table";

    $result = $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'icon' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['icon']), 
            'text' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['text']), 
        )
    );

    if ( $result == false ) {
        wp_send_json_success( 'Link has been created' );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }

    wp_die();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_link', 'create_link' );
```

Javascript

```
( function( $ ) {

    $( document ).ready( function() {

        $( '.ufb-create' ).on( 'click', '.ufb-btn', function( event ) {

            var $button = $( this );

            $button.prop('disabled', true);

            var data = {
                'action' : 'create_link',
                'nonce'  : $button.data('nonce'),
                'icon' : $('.icon-input').val(),
                'text' : $('.text-input').val()
            };
        
            $.post(ajaxurl, data )
            .done( function (response) {

                console.log( response );

                if ( response.success == true ) {
                    // display success message
                    $('.ufb-create-response').html( response.data );

                } else {

                    // display error message
                    $( '.ufb-create-response' ).html("Something went wrong");
            
                }
                
                // enable button
                $button.prop('disabled', false);
            
            })
            .fail( function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            });
            
        
        } );        

    });

})( jQuery );
```

console.log(success)

```
{ "success": false }
```

Any help, please.

Comment: Try replacing `( $result == false ) ` with just `( $result ) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your condition at the end:

```
if ( $result == false ) {
    wp_send_json_success( 'Link has been created' );
} else {
    wp_send_json_error();
}
```

`wpdb::insert()` returns `false` when there's an error, so you're only returning a success response when there's an error. You need to swap the statement around.

```
if ( $result == false ) {
    wp_send_json_error();
} else {
    wp_send_json_success( 'Link has been created' );
}
```